# URl with controller/method is not working only URl query parameter is working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-3

URl with controller/method is not working only URl query parameter is working in CodeIgniter 3.1.1.

My Working URL

```
https://example.abc.com/?c=home&m=products&id=14&
```

Below Url Not working(even tried with index.php)

```
https://example.abc.com/home
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

route file

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Is that your actual `.htaccess` file? What version of Apache are you using? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled? (I guess not, since the `.htaccess` file you've posted is invalid and should "break" if it was.)

Comment: @MrWhite .htaccess updated in question

Comment: @MrWhite We are using nginx sever

Comment: `.htaccess` is an Apache config file - Nginx doesn't use `.htaccess`!